# Match a length of string in column using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to extract the column which matches the date pattern like: `YYYY-MM-DD`, but didn't understand the difference between below commands

Working command

```
echo 1,2,3,4,2015-12-34 | awk -F, '{if($5~/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]$/) print $1}'
```

Not working command

```
echo 1,2,3,4,2015-12-34 | awk -F, '{if($5~/^[0-9]{d}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/)print $1}'
```

Can someone explain me why it's happening, am i missing a granular thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
echo 1,2,3,4,2015-12-34 | awk --re-interval -F, '{if($5~/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/)print $1}'
```

***OR***

```
echo 1,2,3,4,2015-12-34 | awk --re-interval -F, 'match($NF,/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/){print $1}'
```

***NOTE:*** My `awk` version is OLD so I am using `--re-interval` you could remove it in case you have recent `awk` version.

Comment: Ahhhh.. seems my `awk` version is also old, I didn't check that. Mine `Awk 3.1.7`. with --re-interval its working on mine too. Thanks @Ravinder

Comment: nbd but `/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/`= `/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/`